# Android Wear Os using phone and watch app together

Tags: android, wear-os

I want to make an application that can be controlled from the application on the phone at the same time with Android wear os. I would appreciate it if you could suggest a source or an example for this.

Answer (score 1):

[Android XYZTouristAttractions Sample](https://github.com/bitrise-io/sample-apps-wear-os) is good place to start
[image: wear os app]

> This sample aims to be as close to a real world example of a mobile and Wear app combination as possible. It has a more refined design and also provides a practical example of how a mobile app would interact and communicate with its wear counterpart.